# Web API Quick Start Sample

Tags: c#, dynamics-365

I'm working on integration with Dynamics 365 and following the [Web API Sample (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/quick-start-console-app-csharp). While this works, there are two issues with the sample that I'd like to understand how to deal with.

First, the sample uses an old version of the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` package, and it explains that this is because:

> This sample depends on the capability to pass user credentials without a separate Azure login dialog which is not available in the 3.x version of this library.

Secondly, the sample uses this hardcoded clientId from Microsoft:

```
// Azure Active Directory registered app clientid for Microsoft samples
string clientId = "51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d";
```

Given that I'm using Office365 accounts and I can't see how Azure fits into the picture at all, what is the best way to achieve connectivity with Dynamics365 without the issues mentioned above?

Comment: You will need to authenticate your CRM with authentication user.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/debajitcrm/archive/2018/08/16/step-by-step-guide-query-dynamics-crm-web-api-using-server-to-server-authentication-with-application-user

and with postman here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/setup-postman-environment

Answer (score 1):

A fast way to start with C# Dynamics 365 extensions is by using the SDK, available in NuGet (XrmTooling). This way you can use a [connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect?view=op-9-1#connection-string-parameters) with a ClientId and SecretKey using Authorization Type **ClientSecret**. Here is an example of the code using a [WhoAmIRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.whoamirequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) and requires using an application user, [here is how to do it](https://readyxrm.blog/2020/10/30/how-to-setup-a-common-data-service-application-user-and-why/)

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var urlMask = "RequireNewInstance=True;SkipDiscovery=True;AuthType=ClientSecret;LoginPrompt=Never;ClientSecret={0};ClientId={1};Url={2};AppId=51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d;RedirectUri=app://58145b91-0c36-4500-8554-080854f2ac97/";
var fullUrl = string.Format(urlMask, clientSecret, clientId, d365Url);

var conn = new CrmServiceClient(fullUrl);
var _orgService = conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient ?? (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;

WhoAmIRequest req = new WhoAmIRequest();
WhoAmIResponse resp = _orgService.Execute(req) as WhoAmIResponse;

Console.Write(resp.UserId);
```

Comment: This was a great example, but for anyone reading currently, this authtype is deprecated.  You can download the CRM SDK QuickStart sample code, but at the moment that uses Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory library from NUGET and that package is also deprecated.  So as of today there's no completely updated example.